# Onde colocar o código do Model no php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho algumas tabelas no meu db entre elas estão

```
post_has_categoria
post
categoria
```

em Meus Models eu tenho o Categoria.php e o Concurso.php
aonde deveria ficar o sql responsavel pelo post_has_categoria?

Comment: Pra mim cada tabela deve ser representada por um _model_. Mas acredito que isso também tenha algo a ver com a sua lógica. Talvez tenha relação com opinião pessoal...

Comment: Você está utilizando algum ORM para realizar as consultas ou está fazendo tudo na mão?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partindo do pressuposto que esse sql/método faria a verificação "existe categoria no post?", esse mesmo sql/método ficaria na classe Post seguindo o padrão IE (information Expert) - quem tem/conhece a informação é que deve realizar a tarefa. Neste caso, só a classe Post sabe se tem categoria.

Comment: Pô, me interessei. É bom deixar fonte sobre essas coisas, Information Expert é parte do padrão MVC mesmo, ou uma coisa à parte?

Comment: @Daniel na minha pesquisa eu achei esse [Padrão para atribuir responsabilidades: Expert](http://www.dsc.ufcg.edu.br/~jacques/cursos/map/html/pat/expert.htm)

Comment: @Daniel o information expert é um padrão de softwareque faz parte dos principios de design GRASP que diz que a classe que faz determinada ação é aquela que tem conhecimento para tal! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)